# ASP.Net Web Api project: Preferred download location

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

In a project we are working on we download a file (daily) from the web, that we then use in our code. The web app runs on an IIS server. Where would be the ideal location to download this file to? For development purposes we used "c:/temp/". Is the App_data folder used for things like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ideal location.

The only thing that you have to take into account is that the Application Pool user defined in IIS has the necessary permissions on the chosen folder.

The easiest way to do it is to include it in a folder inside the web site directory. But this has a drawback: if you redeploy the web site code, you must take care not to delete that folder. So I usually prefer a folder outside the web site directory.

If you have an ad-hoc user in the app pool, giving the necessary permissions to that folder is done as usual. If it's the default user, then you have to do it in an special way, please, see this: [How to assign permissions to ApplicationPoolIdentity account](https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account) This link basically shows that you have to give permissions to a user whose name is: `IIS APPPOOL\{app pool name}`, for example `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`. You must type it, as it doesn't appear in any search or listing of users (because it's an special user which is created dynamically when the application pool starts).

Comment: If it's a local folder inside the web site directory, would I still need special permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: No, it usually have enough permissions. If so, I recommend you to create the folder inside AppData standard folder.